# use perl to extract a substring between two delimiters and store as a new string

Tags: perl

I am working on a Perl script, and I want to split a string between two different variables.

This is my string

```
<p>Hello my server number is 1221.899999 , please select an option</p>
```

I want to be able to extract the server number, so I want to split the string after  `<p>Hello my server number is` and before the following space, so my end string would print as

```
1221.899999
```

Is regex the best solution for this, rather than using split?

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a regex.

```
my $str = 'Hello my server number is 1221.899999 , please select an option';
my ($num) = $str =~ /Hello my server number is (\d+\.\d+) ,/;
```

`$num` will be undefined if the match didn't succeed.

Comment: $str =~ /Hello my server number is (\S+) ,/; in case I got a server name like "Hello my server number is 104/238,12.1 , please select an option"

Comment: @Aldo 's solution answers my question :)

Comment: @Nongo Aldo's solution doesn't match against numbers, it will grab anything after an `is`. Seems more specific would be better in this case.

Comment: The solution won't match against numbers but the solution will extract the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$str = 'Hello my server number is 1221.899999 , please select an option';
$str =~ s/^.*\b(\d+\.\d+)\b.*$/$1/;
say $str;
```

or

```
$str =~ s/^Hello my server number is (\d+\.\d+)\s.*$/$1/;
```

If the begining of the string is always that.

**output:**

```
1221.899999
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex. How about this:

```
$str = 'Hello my server number is 1221.899999 , please select an option';
print $1 if $str =~ /is (.*) ,/;
```

Comment: It doesn't work with the sentance:  `This is my server number 123.456 , yes it is`.

Comment: For that specific case the regex is: /number (.*) ,/

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are *sure* that there is always a space before the comma, the proper answer is something similar to this

```
my $string = '<p>Hello my server number is 1221.899999 , please select an option</p>';

my ($server) = $string =~ /server number is (\S+)/;

print $server;
```

**output**

```
1221.899999
```

If the comma could appear immediately after the end of the server number then you would need to modifiy is slightly to this

```
my ($server) = $string =~ /server number is ([^\s,]+)/;
```